How to find the series expansion or asymptotic behavior of $Q(x)=\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{e^{-t}}{x-t}dt, x\in(0,+\infty)$?
First give the definition of this integral as
$$Q(x)=\lim\limits_{y\to 0+}\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{(x-t)e^{-t}}{(x-t)^2+y^2}dt.$$
Numerical results show that
$$\lim\limits_{x\to+\infty}xQ(x)=1$$
but I can't prove it. Also, I have no idea of the asymptotic behavior of $Q(x)$ when $x\to 0+$. I wonder if there are any methods to analyze this function such as series expansion or asymptotic behavior.
This function is related to the exponential integral
$$Q(x)=e^x Ei(x)$$
and a confluent hypergeometric function
$$Q(x)=U(1,1,-x)$$

For: x->Infinity we have :$\int_0^{\infty } \frac{\exp (-t)}{x-t} , dt\approx \frac{24}{x^5}+\frac{6}{x^4}+\frac{2}{x^3}+\frac{1}{x^2}+\frac{1}{x}$

$$Q(y,x)=\int_0^\infty\frac{(x-t)e^{-t}}{(x-t)^2+y^2}dt\overset {IBP}{=}-\frac12\ln\big((t-x)^2+y^2\big)e^{-t},\bigg|0^\infty-\frac12\int_0^\infty\ln\big((t-x)^2+y^2\big)e^{-t}dt$$
Both terms are regular at $y=0$; dropping exponentially small terms and decomposing logarithm in the last line
$$Q(y=0;x)=\ln x-\int_0^x\ln(x-t)e^{-t}dt-\int_x^\infty\ln(t-x)e^{-t}dt$$
$$=\ln x-\ln x\int_0^xe^{-t}dt-\int_0^x\ln\Big(1-\frac tx\Big)e^{-t}dt+\gamma, e^{-x}\sim\sum{k=1}^\infty\frac{(k-1)!}{x^k},,\text{at},,x\to\infty$$

Unfortunately, this series doesn't converge for any $x>0$. Maybe series isn't a good way.

We can compute every thing for
$$Q(x,y)=\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{(x-t)\,e^{-t}}{(x-t)^2+y^2}\,dt$$
First, the antiderivative
$$\int\frac{(x-t)\,e^{-t}}{(x-t)^2+y^2}\,dt=-e^{-x}\int \frac{e^{-u}\, u}{u^2+y^2}\,du$$
$$\int \frac{e^{-u}\, u}{u^2+y^2}\,du=\int \frac{e^{-u} u}{(u-i y) (u+i y)}\,du=\frac 12\Bigg(\int \frac{e^{-u}}{u-i y }\,du+\int \frac{e^{-u}}{u+i y }\,du\Bigg)$$
$$\int \frac{e^{-u}\, u}{u^2+y^2}\,du=\frac 12 \Big(e^{i y} \,\text{Ei}(-u-i y)+e^{-i y}\, \text{Ei}(-u+i y)   \Big)$$
$$\int\frac{(x-t)\,e^{-t}}{(x-t)^2+y^2}\,dt=-\frac {e^{-x}}2 \Big(e^{i y}\, \text{Ei}(-t+x-i y)+e^{-i y}\ \text{Ei}(-t+x+i y)   \Big)$$
$$Q(x,y)=\frac {e^{-x}}2 \Big( e^{i y}\, \text{Ei}(x-i y)+e^{-i y}\,
   \text{Ei}(x+i y)-2 \pi \sin(y) \Big)$$
$$\large\color{blue}{Q(x,0)=e^{-x} \,\text{Ei}(x)}$$
Expanding as a non-convergent series
$$Q(x,0)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac {\Gamma(n)}{x^n}$$
Around $x=0$, with $L=\log(x)+\gamma$,
$$Q(x,0)=L+(1-L)x+\frac{2 L-3}{4} x^2+\frac{11-6 L}{36} x^3+\frac{12 L-25}{288} x^4+O(x^5 )$$

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[15px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{{\displaystyle #1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\iverson}[1]{\left[\left[\,{#1}\,\right]\right]}
 \newcommand{\on}[1]{\operatorname{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\sr}[2]{\,\,\,\stackrel{{#1}}{{#2}}\,\,\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}
\color{#44f}{\left.\rule{0pt}{5mm}\on{Q}\pars{x}\right\vert_{x\ >\ 0}} & \equiv\color{#44f}{\lim_{y\ \to\ 0^{+}}\
\int_{0}^{\infty}{\pars{x - t}\expo{-t} \over
\pars{x - t}^{2} + y^{2}}\,\dd t}
\\[5mm] & =
-\,{1 \over 2}\int_{0}^{\infty}
\expo{-t}\pars{{1 \over t - x  + \ic 0^{+}} +
{1 \over t - x  - \ic 0^{+}}}\dd t
\\[5mm] & =
-\,\Re\int_{0}^{\infty}
{\expo{-t} \over t - x  + \ic 0^{+}}\dd t
\\[5mm] & =
-\,\Re\braces{{\rm P.V.}\int_{0}^{\infty}\!\!\!
{\expo{-t} \over t - x}\dd t - \int_{0}^{\infty}
\!\!\!\!\!\expo{-t}\bracks{\ic\pi\,\delta\pars{t - x}}\dd t}
\\[5mm] & =
-{\rm P.V.}\int_{0}^{\infty}{\expo{-t} \over t - x}
\dd t = -\expo{-x}\,{\rm P.V.}\int_{-x}^{\infty}{\expo{-t} \over t}\dd t
\\[5mm] & =
-\expo{-x}\bracks{\int_{-x}^{x}{\expo{-t} \over t}\dd t + \int_{x}^{\infty}{\expo{-t} \over t}\dd t}
\\[5mm] & =
-\expo{-x}\bracks{-2\int_{0}^{x}{\sinh\pars{t}\over t}\dd t + \int_{x}^{\infty}{\expo{-t} \over t}\dd t}
\\[5mm] & =
\bbx{\color{#44f}{\expo{-x}\bracks{2\on{Shi}\pars{x}  -
\on{E}_{1}\pars{x}}}}
\end{align}
$\ds{\on{Shi}}$ and $\ds{\on{E}_{1}}$ are the Hyperbolic Sine Integral Function and the Exponential Integral Function, respectively.
Asymptotic values of them , as $\ds{x \to \infty}$, are well known or/and can be easily found by $\underline{\color{red}{\mbox{integration by parts}}}$ of the above integral representations. Namely,
$$
\left\{\begin{array}{rcl}
\ds{\on{Shi}\pars{x}} & \ds{{\rm as}\ x\ \to\ \infty \atop {\LARGE\sim}} & \ds{{\cosh\pars{x} \over x} + {\sinh\pars{x} \over x^{2}}}
\\[2mm]
\ds{\on{E}_{1}\pars{x}} & \ds{{\rm as}\ x\ \to\ \infty \atop {\LARGE\sim}} & \ds{{\expo{-x} \over x} - {\expo{-x} \over x^{2}}}
\end{array}\right.
$$
such that
\begin{align}
\color{#44f}{x\on{Q}\pars{x}} & \sr{{\rm as}\ x\ \to\ \infty}{\sim} \pars{1 + \expo{-2x}} - \pars{\expo{-2x} - {\expo{-2x} \over x}}
\\ & \sr{{\rm as}\ x\ \to\ \infty}{\sim}
1 + {\expo{-2x} \over x}
\sr{{\rm as}\ x\ \to\ \infty}{\to}
\bbx{\color{#44f}{\large 1}} \\ &
\end{align}

Good idea to use $\text{Shi}(x)$. But I think that we could go further and write the result as $\text{Chi}(x)+\text{Shi}(x)$
